# Script to identify PID of service then use discovered PID

Tags: automation, scripting

Bit of a linux noob sorry, apologies if this seems really obvious.

I want to automate a media server bypassing a vpn client. Currently I have to lookup the PID of the media server and then enter that PID as a variable of another command.

Is there a way of looking up said PID and then auto creating/running the follow up command?

Thanks in advance.

#!/usr/bin/bash
vpn split-tunnel pid add $(pgrep mediaserver)

pgrep mediaserver returns nothing